# Group data in a 3d array by its second level keys and sum the 3rd level values per group

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, grouping

I need to reduce an array with 3 levels to an associative array of sums.

```
$consumption = [
    'MONDAY' => [
        'REFRIGERATOR' => [3, 9, 7],
        'WASHINGMACHINE' => [2, 4, 2, 8]
    ],
    'TUESDAY' => [
        'REFRIGERATOR' => [5, 3, 8],
        'OVEN' => [4, 1, 4]
    ],
    'WEDNESDAY' => [
        'TV' => [6, 9],
        'REFRIGERATOR' => [2, 3, 5, 2]
    ],
    'THURSDAY' => [
        'TV' => [5, 3, 3, 2],
        'FAN' => [4, 9, 8, 5]
    ],
    'FRIDAY' => [
        'WASHINGMACHINE' => [8, 5],
        'OVEN' => [3, 9, 7]
    ]
];
```

I need to get the output as:

```
$sum = Array (
    [REFRIGERATOR] => 47,
    [WASHINGMACHINE] => 29,
    [OVEN] => 28,
    [TV] => 28,
    [FAN] => 26
);
```

Answer (score 4):

You're looking to store each of these on a key and increment the total in the array. Iterate through each of the entries, and go from there:

```
$sums = array();
foreach ($consumption as $day=>$products) {
    foreach ($products as $product=>$sales) {
        if (!isset($sums[$product])) {
            $sums[$product] = 0;
        }
        $sums[$product] += array_sum($sales);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

check the result [here](https://eval.in/684680)

```
<?php
    $consumption = array( 'MONDAY' => array('REFRIGERATOR' => array(3, 9, 7), 'WASHINGMACHINE' => array(2, 4, 2, 8)), 'TUESDAY' => array('REFRIGERATOR' => array(5, 3, 8), 'OVEN' => array(4, 1, 4)), 'WEDNESDAY' => array('TV' => array(6, 9), 'REFRIGERATOR' => array(2, 3, 5, 2)), 'THURSDAY' => array('TV' => array(5, 3, 3, 2), 'FAN' => array(4, 9, 8, 5)), 'FRIDAY' => array('WASHINGMACHINE' => array(8, 5), 'OVEN' => array(3, 9, 7)) );

    $result = [];
    foreach($consumption as $dayCon)
    {
      array_walk($dayCon, function($value, $key) use(&$result)
      {
     if(!isset($result[$key]))
        $result[$key] = 0;

         $result[$key] += array_sum($value);
      });
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Functional iteration only adds unwelcomed convolution to this task. Just use nested `foreach()` loops and, per unique set key, add the current values sum to the stored amount or zero.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/auRYR))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $set) {
    foreach ($set as $k => $values) {
        $result[$k] = ($result[$k] ?? 0) + array_sum($values);
    }
}
var_export($result);
```